# Rewriting $1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots+x^{16}-x^{17}$ using sum of geometric series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> From the AIME 1986, the polynomial $1-x+x^2-x^3+...+x^{16}-x^{17}$ may be written in the form $a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2+a_3y^3+...a_{16}y^{16}+a_{17}y^{17}$, where $y=x+1$ and the $a_is$ are constants. Find the value of $a_2$.

My attempt,

By sum of geometric sequence, $$S_n=a_1 \cdot \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

$$=1 \cdot \frac{-x^{18}+1}{-x-1}$$

But the solution provided states that $$\frac{1-x^{18}}{x+1}$$

It's clearly that my form is not same with the solution provided. What's wrong with my step?

Comment: What is $r$, what is $S_n$ ? Why does $a_1$ appear in the expression of $S_n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to look at this:

$$\begin{align}
1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots&=\frac 1{1+x}\tag{1}\\
x^{18}(1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots)&=x^{18}\cdot \frac 1{1+x}\tag{2}\\
(1)-(2):\hspace{5cm}\\
S=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots -x^{17} &=\color{red}{\frac {\;\;1-x^{18}}{1+x}}\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

---

The question asks for $[y^2] S$ where $y=x+1$.

Putting $y=x+1$ in $(3)$ gives
$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac {1-(1-y)^{18}}y\\
&=\frac {1-(1-18y+\binom {18}2 y^2-\binom {18}3 y^3+\cdots)}y\\
&=18-\binom {18}2y+\binom {18}3 y^2-\cdots\end{align}$$
Hence $$a_2=[y^2]S=\color{red}{\binom {18}3}$$

Alternatively, using $-x=1-y$, we have

$$\begin{align}
[y^2]S
&=[y^2]\sum_{n=0}^{17}(1-y)^n\\
&=[y^2]\sum_{n=0}^{17}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr(-y)^r\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{17}\binom n2\\
&=\color{red}{\binom {18}3}\end{align}$$
Note that in this method the answer is derived directly without first having to evaluate $S$.

Answer (score 3):

You miswrote $(-x)^{18}=-x^{18}$. Rather, it should be $x^{18}$. So $$S_n = 1\cdot \frac{(-x)^{18}-1}{-x-1} = \frac{1-x^{18}}{x+1}$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Since $r=-x$ we have $$S_n = \frac{(-x)^{18} -1 }{-x - 1} \iff S_n=\frac{x^{18} -1}{-(x+1)} = \frac{1-x^{18}}{1+x} $$

---

Note that you made two mistakes: $(-x)^{18} \neq -x^{18}$ since $18$ is even and your numerator should be $r^n-1$, not $r^n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the sum be $S(x)$. By the geometric summation formula,

$$S(x)=\frac{(-x)^{18}-1}{-x-1}=\frac{1-x^{18}}{x+1}=\frac{1-(y-1)^{18}}y.$$

By the Binomial theerm,

$$=\frac{1-1+18y-\dfrac{18\cdot17}2y^2+\dfrac{18\cdot17\cdot16}{2\cdot3}y^3-\cdots}y.$$

Hence $$a_2=816.$$

Comment: [Late crossed with @hypergeometric after connection loss.]